# Slowly print text to a JLabel from a String?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to do a Pokemon style print inside of a JLabel, but due to its limitations I've been unable to do this successfully. I was able to accomplish this task for simply printing to the console using the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(test.charAt(i));
        Thread.sleep(35);
    }
```

However, because a JLabel can't accept the Char datatype, this approach doesn't work. Because of this, i tried setting a string to that char using this:

```
while (pos < text.length() - 1) {
            char test = text.charAt(pos);
            String print = String.valueOf(test);
            label.setText(print);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(35);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            pos++;
        }
```

However, I then ran into the issue of the text not adding onto what was there during the previous time through the loop.

Is there another way I can accomplish this task of slowly printing text?

Comment: 1) `Thread.sleep(35);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) *"text not adding onto what was there"* it will be necessary to append the text to the existing text in the label: `label.setText(label.setText() + print);` 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is NOT thread safe and is SINGLE threaded.

You can't block the Event Dispatching Thread, otherwise nothing gets painted and you shouldn't update the UI or anything the UI relies on from outside the context of the EDT

- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for why your current solution doesn't work/shouldn't be used
- [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the solution to your problem

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String text = "All your base belong to us";
        private int index;

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("");

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);

            Timer timer = new Timer(35, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    label.setText(text.substring(0, index));
                    index++;
                    if (index > text.length()) {
                        ((Timer) evt.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly clicked something together that should resemble what you need:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Kai
 */
public class Pokemon extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String text = "someTesttext";
    StringBuffer current = new StringBuffer();

    /**
     * Creates new form Pokemon
     */
    public Pokemon() {
        initComponents();
        new javax.swing.Timer(150, event -> {
            if (current.length() == text.length()) {
                current.setLength(0);
            } else {
                current.append(text.charAt(current.length()));
            }
            this.jLabel1.setText(current.toString());

        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(41, 23, 240, 30);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Pokemon().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: [*"As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and don't get me started on `null` layouts

Comment: ;) yes I do know that too.

Comment: the ops application will differ anyways. but he will be able to get over the obstacle that got him stuck. if you look close, 90% of the code was automaticaly created: like I wrote, "i clicked it together".... good enough;)

Comment: *"good enough"* - With two glaring omissions, which provide an opportunity for a novice developer to learn bad habits/code ... Is this level of quantity you want from you questions?

Comment: sure, if I asked the question: I'd think ahh, thats the point where i got stuck and then create my own code.  Well I wouldn't use swing anymore in the first place as its developement is also discontinued. So...

Comment: Well, you're smarter then most posters I've come across :P

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just put the string outside the while loop then add to it.
Something like this:

```
String print = ""; // add this line
while (pos < text.length() - 1) {
            char test = text.charAt(pos);
            print = print + String.valueOf(test); // add to the print
            label.setText(print);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(35);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            pos++;
        }
```